# SandCastle Help File Builder and MAML, how to have an ordered list with a different starting index?

Tags: list, sandcastle, maml, shfb

I'm using SandCastle Help File Builder 1.8.0.1 with its MAML content editor.

I want an ordered list starting from a value other than the default of 1.

> `10. Some data`
>
> `11. Other data`

I even tried the following and it does not work as it is from HTML for the OL element:

```
<list class="ordered">
     <listItem value="10">some data</listItem>
</list>
```

How can I achieve this?

Does someone knows what files should I modify in the sandcastle styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of SandCastle supports

```
<list class="ordered" start="9">
  <listItem>Item 9</listItem>
</list>
```